# Json sort is not working

Tags: javascript, json, google-cloud-functions

my json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "cash": 100,
    "uid": "LHy2qRGaf3nkWQgU4axO",
    "name": "test2"
  },
  {
    "cash": 1000000,
    "uid": "01wFhCSlnd9vSDY4NIkx",
    "name": "test"
  },
  {
    "cash": 500,
    "uid": "PBOhla0jPwI4PIeNmmPg",
    "name": "test3"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to sort the json by the user cash. 
So what I did is :

```
    var objArr = []; // the json array

    function compare(a, b) {
        console.log("a" + a.cash);
        console.log("b" + b.cash);
        if (a.cash > b.cash)
            return -1;
        if (a.cash < b.cash)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

   var obj = objArr.sort(compare);
   response.send(obj);
```

but the response that came back is not ordered.

how can I fix it?
thanks

Comment: actually it is sorting descending. do you need an ascending sorting?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @NinaScholz It doesn't matter. the response is not sorted at all

Comment: maybe it's a timing problem, you sort the array before you have the data to sort.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes:

1. Your code is sorting in *descending* order (it's not unordered).
2. Your code is using the return value of `sort`. Just beware that that gives the misleading impression that the returned array is not the same array as the original. It is the same array, so generally best not to use the return value.
3. Your sort can be much shorter:

   ```
   // Ascending:
   return a.cash - bcash;

   // Or descending:
   return b.cash - a.cash;
   ```

Proof of #1 above:

```js
var objArr = [
  {
    "cash": 100,
    "uid": "LHy2qRGaf3nkWQgU4axO",
    "name": "test2"
  },
  {
    "cash": 1000000,
    "uid": "01wFhCSlnd9vSDY4NIkx",
    "name": "test"
  },
  {
    "cash": 500,
    "uid": "PBOhla0jPwI4PIeNmmPg",
    "name": "test3"
  }
];

function compare(a, b) {
  console.log("a" + a.cash);
  console.log("b" + b.cash);
  if (a.cash > b.cash)
    return -1;
  if (a.cash < b.cash)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

var obj = objArr.sort(compare);
console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Demo of #2 and #3:

```js
var objArr = [
  {
    "cash": 100,
    "uid": "LHy2qRGaf3nkWQgU4axO",
    "name": "test2"
  },
  {
    "cash": 1000000,
    "uid": "01wFhCSlnd9vSDY4NIkx",
    "name": "test"
  },
  {
    "cash": 500,
    "uid": "PBOhla0jPwI4PIeNmmPg",
    "name": "test3"
  }
];

console.log("ascending", objArr.sort((a, b) => a.cash - b.cash));
console.log("descending", objArr.sort((a, b) => b.cash - a.cash))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that it works here. also, the code I post in question works here. the problem is with the response still come unsorted

Comment: @ULAQ: What is `response.send`?

Comment: @ULAQ: "Yes"? That comment has nothing to do with my question above.

Comment: @ULAQ: Again, that has nothing whatsoever to do with my question above. If you won't answer the questions people ask you, we can't help you.

Comment: response.send is how i sent the request response inside my function 
`exports.getTopFive = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
response.send(obj);
});`